# How to get Prestashop current user id?

Tags: prestashop, custom-error-pages

I used the below code to try to get the current user ID in prestashop..
am placing this code in another php file in my module directory and call it through by the module file.

```
 $id = $this->context->customer->id_customer;
```

but its not working for me.. am using prestashop 1.5 ..

Comment: Can you give more details ? What are you trying to do in your php file ? Are you in front or back office ? Is your php file called with ajax ?
We need the context to understand where the problem can come from.

Comment: I already got the answer AlexDeb

Comment: http://blog.gofenice.com/uncategorized/get-current-user-id-prestashop/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I certainly couldn't get it to work in my test either. However, you can try

```
$id = (int)$this->context->cookie->id_customer;
```

which works for me. I'm not at all sure that this is the best way to do it though.

Answer (score 7):

First check if user is logged in than get the id by `$this->context->customer->id_customer`

```
if ($this->context->customer->isLogged()) {

      echo $this->context->customer->id_customer;

}
else{
   echo 'Not LoggedIn';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be using cookie.

Just use this:

```
    $id=(int)$this->context->customer->id;
```

you can remove (int), but i like to specify the type of content im getting.

BR's

Answer (score 4):

In Prestashop 1.6, the best way in a controller is to use :

```
        $id_customer = null;
        if ($this->context->customer->isLogged()) {
            // code to execute if i am logued
             $id_customer = $this->context->customer->id;
        }
```