# Getting same customer id for different account in Prestashop

Tags: variables, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I have module in Prestashop, where I need the current customer id.
Here is my code in module php file:

```
$userid =(int)$this->context->customer->id;
$this->context->smarty->assign('userid',$userid);
```

I use this variable like parameter for custom link.
This work fine, but every time get same ID. I mean...for different users.
What could be the reason for this?

Comment: You should first check in PHP what is $userId value. You should make sure it changes for different users.

Comment: $userid return "2" for each user.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try:

```
$id = (int)$this->context->cookie->id_customer;
```

Comment: Same result Marcin...I loged in with user(id = 5) but result is 2.

Comment: I've changed my answer. You can try it. I found similar topic at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231440/how-to-get-prestashop-current-user-id

Comment: I'm really confused! Today I logged in shop, first with user(id =5). And result was good...I have my custom link in module with current id(5). After that I logged out and entered again with user(id=2). Result was link with parameter id=5...
Is there any chance...that old cookie can't be destroyed?...Or something similar?

Comment: I really don't know. I don't use Prestashop

Comment: Thanks anyway Marcin.